# The fullscreenmode is incorrect size of stack on platform desktop in Livecode

Tags: livecode

I create stack and set width to "2048" and height to "1536". It's size iPad Retina. But I want to build application to desktop.

I input this code in my stack:

```
on preopenstack
   if environment() is "mobile" then
      set the fullscreenmode of this stack to "exactFit"
      set the acceleratedRendering of this stack to true
   else
      set the fullscreenmode of this stack to "showAll"
      set the acceleratedRendering of this stack to false
   end if
end preopenstack
```

After I save standalone application to desktop. Size of stack has incorrect.

This picture
[image]
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to use the "fullscreen" property if you wish to have your app run as full screen within the desktop environment.

The following amended preopenstack script should work

```
on preopenstack
  if environment() is "mobile" then
    set the fullscreenmode of this stack to "exactFit"
    set the acceleratedRendering of this stack to true
  else
    set the fullscreenmode of this stack to "showAll"
    set the acceleratedRendering of this stack to false
    set the fullscreen of this stack to true
 end if
end preopenstack
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I don't want to fullscreen. But I want to fit screen size of stack. Have any way?

Comment: the screenRect function should allow you to accomplish this. You could use something like: set the rect of this stack to the screenrect: and this would fit the stack to the size of the screen